# Cannot convert undefined or null to object in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem about implementing conditional rending in return part of functional component.

I got this kind of error shown below.

```
Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

While some links have more than one link, others have only one link.

How can I fix my issue?

Here is my code shown below.

```
{Object.keys(projectDialog?.links).length > 1 ? (

                projectDialog?.links 
                  .map((link, index) => (
                      <a href={link.link} target="_blank" key={index} className="projectDialog_icons">{link.icon}</a>
                ))
              ) : (
                <a href={projectDialog?.links.link} target="_blank" className="projectDialog_icons">{projectDialog?.links.icon}</a>
              )
            }
```

Comment: The error you are getting is from this part of the code `Object.keys(projectDialog?.links)`. `projectDialog` or `projectDialog?.links` is `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: probably on initial render you pass projectDialog which is null at that time - just add another conditional rendering over current render: `projectDialog ? <render links> : <render placeholder>`

Answer (score 1):

You need additional check for cases if `projectDialog` or `projectDialog?.links` are `null` or `undefined`, for better readability and prevent from nested ternary conditional rendering I would write in such way:

```
...
if (!projectDialog || !projectDialog?.links) return null;
//after above check you can be sure that below return will be with defined values
return (
 {Object.keys(projectDialog?.links).length > 1 ? (
    projectDialog?.links.map((link, index) => (
       <a href={link.link} target="_blank" key={index} className="projectDialog_icons">{link.icon}</a>
                ))
              ) : (
                <a href={projectDialog?.links.link} target="_blank" className="projectDialog_icons">{projectDialog?.links.icon}</a>
              )
            }
)
```